# Issue with setting a .htaccess single redirect scheme on apache server, dont know why it acts this way

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, optimization

I have been trying to set up a .htaccess redirect scheme in order to enable single-step redirects for a website on Apache Linux server:

The redirect rules should be the following:
- If not on https, redirect to https
- if its example.com, redirect to www.example.com
- If it doesnt end with trailing slash "/" , add a trailing slash.

Using redirect checker, i got the following results:

```
http://www.example.com/articles/   - 1 redirect
http://www.example.com/articles   - 1 redirect
http://example.com/articles/   - 1 redirect
http://example.com/articles   - 1 redirect
https://www.example.com/articles/   - 0 redirect- proper destination
https://www.example.com/articles   - 1 redirect
https://example.com/articles/   - 1 redirect
https://example.com/articles   - 2 redirect (https://example.com/articles/ -> https://www.example.com/articles/)
```

The last one is the one I cant figure out why

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ https://www.example\.com/$1$2/ [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ "https://www.example\.com/$1$2/ [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)([/])$ https://www.example\.com/$1$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)([/])$ https://www.example.com/$1$2 [R=301,L]

(backup trailing slash redirect, just in case)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$        /$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What are those `<br />` doing in a dynamic configuration file?

Comment: Just realised the mistake, first i formatted the code to be ledgeable, then found the code styling .

Comment: There are many examples for redirections from http to https and from non-www to www host names here on SO and out elsewhere on the internet. Yet you implement your own, much more complex rule set. _Why_?

Comment: So far, i was not able to find a single redirect rule for the goal I was trying to achieve. Having this as a separate ruleset, from non-www to www, and http to https, led to slower load times, and also google pagespeed insights advises against multiple redirects.

My goal was to take the entire ruleset and set up single redirect for every situation.

Comment: Sure, you can do that, but it does not really improve much, since those redirections are only done one single time per client, they are not required for any subsequent requests.

Comment: Apart from that you should use `%{HTTPS}` instead of `%{SERVER_PORT}` and I fail to understand why you try to capture a trailing slash in the requests, especially since you manually add one in the redirection target _in addition to that captured one_, which results in a trailing `//`...

Comment: Not sure why that should be of interest...

Comment: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcompanydebt.com%2Farticles

this is what im trying to improve.

Comment: This was already known and I already replied to that.

Comment: I am trying to capture the trailing slash, and then im keeping it if its there,and if trailing slash is missing, i am adding it:

^(.*)([/])$  - if there is trailing slash, /$1$2 keep it as it is.
^(.*)([^/])$ if there is no trailing slash as last character, /$1$2/ add it.

or am i wrong here? I am sorry, im kind of new with the .htaccess redirects.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you can simplify your rule set to that:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/?$ https://www.example.com/$1/ [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/?$ "https://www.example.com/$1/ [R=301]
```

This set should work in the real http servers host configuration and in dynamic configuration files (".htaccess" style files). Since you appear to be extremely interested in performance optimization you definitely should place such rules in the host configuration and *disable* the interpretation of dynamic configuration files completely, since those really slow down the server, often for nothing.

I am not certain about how you actually want to handle your trailing slash issue... The above rule set takes care to always have exactly one single trailing slash which is what you want according to your comments. I would like to mention though that usually one does *not* always want such a trailing slash...

Comment: Thank you! I will give it a try tonight.